# Can't set the default value of some fields in checkout page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I want to put user's previous data at the checkout page fields by default in my website which based on woocommerce. I cant set value for first name, last name and phone fields, although I can set value for other fields. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: WooCommerce will automatically load data entered in the checkout for previous orders out of the box. What kind of 'user's previous data' are you referring to specifically?

Comment: You are correct. I have entered arbitrary data for the first order and woocommerce always put those data in fields and I can't set different values for them programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the WC_Checkout class ([/includes/class-wc-checkout.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/3.6.1/includes/class-wc-checkout.php#L1150-L1199)), it contains a `get_value` method that is responsible for the default methods in the form.

This method has a filter `woocommerce_checkout_get_value` that you can use to override the default value that is loaded for each field.
Here's an example that overrides both the first name (both billing and shipping) and the last name:

```php
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_get_value', function( $value, $input ) {
    // first check if user is logged in
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
        switch ($input) {
            case 'billing_first_name':
            case 'shipping_first_name':
                $value = 'Jack'; // fixed default
                break;
            case 'billing_last_name':
            case 'shipping_last_name':
                $value = $current_user->user_lastname; // use lastname from user profile
                break;

            default:
                // don't change if we don't have substituting data
                break;
        }
    }
    return $value;
},10 ,2 );
```

In the same method there's also a filter `default_checkout_{form_field}` that would let you check existing values first (the former is a short-circuit that prevents the normal default from loading), ex:

```php
add_filter('default_checkout_billing_first_name', 'woocommerce_override_default_checkout_values', 10, 2 );
add_filter('default_checkout_billing_last_name', 'woocommerce_override_default_checkout_values', 10, 2 );
add_filter('default_checkout_shipping_first_name', 'woocommerce_override_default_checkout_values', 10, 2 );
add_filter('default_checkout_shipping_last_name', 'woocommerce_override_default_checkout_values', 10, 2 );
function woocommerce_override_default_checkout_values( $value, $input ) {
    // first check if user is logged in
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        // only load if value is empty
        if (empty($value)) {
            // read your own
            $value = '...';
        }
    }
    return $value;
}
```